# Can "e.Frame.Url" under "FrameLoadEnd" be different?

Tags: cefsharp

Is it possible for "e.Frame.Url" available under "FrameLoadEnd" can be different from "e.Frame.Url" under "FrameLoadStart" event?

Comment: They should be the same. Are you seeing a specific case where they are different?

Comment: Not so far, just guessed so. Now I know. Thanks.